# What's the time reference for this would?

Tags: tense

> A lamp flickered on. It was Hermione Granger, wearing a pink bathrobe
>   and a frown. 
>       "You!" said Ron furiously. "Go back to bed!" 
>       "I almost **told** your brother," Hermione snapped, "Percy –– he's a prefect, **he'd put** a stop to this."
>
> –– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

The highlighted part, I would say, has different Reference Times: *telling*’s RT is the past; *put*’s RT is after the Speech Time. If this is true, I can imagine this sentence: ‘If I told him what you’re going to do, he’d put a stop to this’. Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have it exactly right. It’s a present-tense threat: Hermione is making it very clear to her friends that although she did *not* tell Percy earlier she still *could* tell him, and if she *did* tell him he would put a stop to activities of this sort.